# Great Ruby tracing gem?

Tags: ruby, debugging, trace

Read about this one:

http://unroller.rubyforge.org/

[http://github.com/TylerRick/unroller](http://unroller.rubyforge.org/)

Look at the pictures!

Unfortunately, it's very outdated and not actively maintained.

I wonder, are there any other tools similar to this one that can show me what code was just executed, in what file, what the output was and what the return value was?

Would be so much better than tracing everything manually between the Terminal and a bunch of Ruby files!

Comment: Too noob for that!! Where are all the gurus?

Comment: But this would be a fine way to un-noob!

Comment: @but i like to be noob and ask silly questions!

Answer (score 2):

not as nice as unroller, there is tracer

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Standard_Library/Tracer

and my backtracer gem I believe has a "--tracer" option

http://github.com/rdp/backtracer
That's about it though.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't need diving **that deep** into your code, as mentioned gems do, consider using Cutter gem, I've created to quickly inspect the internals of any given method.

For me it covers the most of the situations when I need to know what's going on in a particular piece of code.

https://rubygems.org/gems/cutter and https://github.com/stanislaw/cutter